# How to process excel file and export back to excel with different table layout?

Tags: excel, powershell, import, export

Please help my inept logic.  I have an weekly entrance log file in excel table format with data as such:

INPUT:

| Name | Date |
| --- | --- |
| Smith, Bob | 4/01/2023 |
| Downs, Suzi | 3/27/2023 |
| Ott, Ed | 3/29/2023 |
| Smith, Bob | 4/01/2023 |

Which I need to output into excel table format as such:

OUTPUT:

| Name | 3/27/2023 | 3/28/2023 | 3/29/2023 | 3/30/2023 | 3/31/2023 | 4/01/2023 | 04/02/2023 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Downs, Suzi | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| Ott, Ed | 0 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| Smith, Bob | 0 | 0 | 2 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |

I'm using Import-Excel module to import the excel file just fine. Please give me your thoughts on how to do the following:

1. Read all dates, eliminate duplicates but required for tallies, and use them for headers.
2. Read all names, eliminate duplicates, and use them for left column in alpha order.
3. Tally up how many times a door was entered on specific date and place them in the column under the appropriate date.

I stared at this for days and can't determine how manipulate this and keep the relationship between the name and the tallied amount.

I don't have any good code as of yet but have been trying to do this with arrays.  I managed to get a list of unique dates but am stymied now.

```
$records = @()
$dates = @()
$uniquedates = @()
$records = import-excel $target\test.xlsx -ImportColumns @(1, 2) 

foreach ($rec in $records){
    $dates += $rec.date 
     
}

foreach ($date in $dates) {
    $uniquedates += $date.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy") 
}

$newdates = $uniquedates | Sort-Object | Get-Unique
```

Comment: You need to add the tag of the coding language you are using.  otherwise it will not get in front of those that can answer.

Comment: Why code? you could approach this with countifs() or index() & match(). I paste the output of a csv file into my Excel sheet to track student's effort calculated as a percentage.